# Unusual character placement on answer screens

Tags: bug, design

For the past few days I've noticed that characters (especially names and badges) are unusually placed. They seem to be either squashed up against other words, sometimes overlapping and something being pushed onto the next line down. Refreshing seems to fix the problem.

I'll take screenshots when I notice it, but here's a minor example of what I mean

[image]

and then after being refreshed

[image]

and more recently;

[image]

Comment: This is possibly related to the css changes associated with the new profile?

Comment: @Pureferret - very possibly. I'm seeing it occasionally rather than frequently.

Comment: I haven't noticed this on any of the sites I regularly browse (this one, SO, Workplace and Puzzling, generally) using FF 37.0.2 on Windows 7. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - Chrome / Windows 8

Comment: I'm also seeing this bug (so far only on SciFi.SE), running Chrome / Windows 7.

Comment: For the record, it's still doing it.

Comment: @Richard It's only being reported on Chrome so far... What version of Chrome are you using? Does it persist if you change versions (if you're able)?

Comment: @CreationEdge - Version 42.0.2311.135 m

Comment: @CreationEdge - Dunno. Let me try to work out how to change versions.

Comment: @Richard It may be worthwhile to also try running Chrome with all extensions disabled, if you have any. [Chrome 42 disabled NPAPI](https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation), which may or may not be affecting your regular extensions.

Comment: I am also seeing this on Chrome.

Comment: I am also seeing this on Chrome

Comment: What operating system are you on? Are you zoomed in/out at all? Any extensions installed? Does this still happen if extensions are disabled?

Comment: @oded - Chrome. Not sure what version (the latest one for windows). No zooming. No extensions

Comment: I too am on windows - I can't reproduce at all. Can you try a hard refresh (`Ctrl + F5`)? Could be a corrupt font file that is cached.

Comment: I'm slaving in the bug mines, and I can't seem to reproduce this. @Richard was this resolved in the recent site design updates, or is this issue still present? Thanks!

Comment: @KurtisBeavers - It seems to have been resolved by the site update. I'll pitch in if I spot it again.